# How to transfer real-time data from Raspberry Pi 3 to iOS device through BlueTooth?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

Question: Shortly, I need transfer real-time data to iPhone through BlueTooth. How to transfer infinity data stream from Raspberry Pi 3 to iPhone?

Scenario: 
I have an ADS-B receiver PiAware. It is based on dump1090. There is a TCP socket port 30003 for keep typing live data like below:

```
telnet 10.0.0.13 30003
```

Result:

```
Trying 10.0.0.13...
Connected to 10.0.0.13.
Escape character is '^]'.
MSG,3,1,1,7C4320,1,2017/07/12,12:57:40.408,2017/07/12,12:57:40.442,,10600,,,-33.73114,151.36912,,,,,,0
MSG,4,1,1,7C4320,1,2017/07/12,12:57:40.448,2017/07/12,12:57:40.495,,,320,175,,,-1536,,,,,0
MSG,3,1,1,7C4320,1,2017/07/12,12:57:40.864,2017/07/12,12:57:40.882,,10600,,,-33.73169,151.36918,,,,,,0
MSG,4,1,1,7C4320,1,2017/07/12,12:57:40.936,2017/07/12,12:57:40.985,,,320,175,,,-1536,,,,,0
MSG,8,1,1,7CF7CD,1,2017/07/12,12:57:40.942,2017/07/12,12:57:40.986,,,,,,,,,,,,-1
MSG,8,1,1,7C4320,1,2017/07/12,12:57:41.018,2017/07/12,12:57:41.045,,,,,,,,,,,,0
MSG,6,1,1,7C4320,1,2017/07/12,12:57:41.082,2017/07/12,12:57:41.101,,,,,,,,1067,0,0,0,
MSG,8,1,1,7C4320,1,2017/07/12,12:57:41.248,2017/07/12,12:57:41.265,,,,,,,,,,,,0
```

I don't wanna change my Debian Raspberry Pi to a WiFi access point. Because the iPhone must connect to the Internet while it connects to Raspberry Pi.

I guess the BlueTooth can be the best way to transfer data.

Again, the question is how to use BlueTooth to transfer infinity real-time data to iOS device?